# Can I print my Spirit boarding pass at some kiosk at the airport, without having to pay $10?

Tags: tickets, fees-and-charges, spirit-airlines, dtw

I just did the online check in for Spirit Airlines (USA) and was told to print the boarding pass, otherwise it'd cost $10 at the airport.

Is there a way for me to print it for free (i.e. without paying that $10) at the airport? Say at some automated kiosk? Briefly googling, this seems to be possible ([1](http://heelsfirsttravel.boardingarea.com/2014/08/22/everything-need-know-spirit-airlines/), [2](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g1-i10702-k7809175-Print_boarding_pass_at_airport-Air_Travel.html)), but I thought I'd get some expert confirmation on StackExchange.

(The airport is DTW (Detroit, MI), if that matters. Also, I don't have any bags to check in)

Comment: Can you print it at home and/or work?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't print it before going to the airport?

Comment: It's Spirit, what do you expect?  They make their money on burying you in fees.

Comment: I don't have a printer where I am.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Last time I flew Spirit, I was able to print my boarding pass at a kiosk without paying an additional fee.  I believe the $10 fee only applies if you get a counter agent to print it for you.

Comment: https://customersupport.spirit.com/hc/en-us/articles/202098006-How-can-I-check-in-and-get-my-boarding-pass- confirms this.

Comment: Yes, confirmed that this is correct, at least for DTW and ACY, and at least for July 2015, and at least if you have no bags to check in.

Comment: As of April 2016, I can also confirm that this is correct at DTW, LGA, and FLL.  It would be hard to imagine a place where this isn't true.

Comment: As of June 2017, this is also correct at MSP and PHL.